# proper replacement for Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, regex

I am replacing some of the code in my cms in preparation of a php upgrade.

this is the code I am replacing :

```
$REQUEST_URI = preg_replace('#([\x3C\x3E])#e', '"%".bin2hex(\'\\1\')', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

this is my replacement:

```
$REQUEST_URI = my_unicode_conv($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
function my_unicode_conv($word) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/([\x3C\x3E])/',create_function ('$matches','return bin2hex($matches[1]);'), $word);
}
```

are these equivalent? how can i test this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often using an eval isn't needed. Let's look at what this code really does.

First of all `\x` means the UTF8 character is specific as hexadecimal. For any number < `7F` this is just ASCII. So we can easily look up those characters in an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

- `\x3C` = "<"
- `\x3E` = ">"

The [`bin2hex`](http://www.php.net/bin2hex) function will give the hexadecimal representation for these characters (so "3C" and "3E").

Also the eval adds "%" in front of the hexadecimal representation.

In short any "<" in the REQUEST_URI is replaced with "%3C" and ">" is replaced with "%3E".

### Solution

Instead of doing the preg_replace, we can simply do a [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/str_replace)

```
$REQUEST_URI = str_replace(['<', '>'], ['%3C', '%3E'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```